# Set default value to select with reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have some function like this:

```
cancel(): void {
  this.form.reset();
  this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { activeOnly: false } });
}
```

And in html like this:

```
<select class="form-control-sm" id="select-process-type" formControlName="processType">
    <option [selected]="!form.get('processType').value" disabled>
        {{'type' | translate}}
    </option>
    <option [value]="'1'" [innerHTML]="'1' | translate">
    </option>
    <option [value]="'2'" [innerHTML]="'2' | translate">
    </option>
    <option [value]="'3'" [innerHTML]="'3' | translate">
    </option>
</select>
```

The problem I have is that when I call

```
  this.form.reset();
```

It clear all value with form, not even first is diplayed, because first option i use like placeholder

Here what it should look

[image]

And this is what it does

[image: reactive]

Comment: Just add the value attribute on first option like `[value]="'Your default value'"` and remove selected atttribute

Comment: I don't know angular but in jquery we can achieve this by follow this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/T8sCf/26/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `[value]="null"` in the default option.

Try like this:

```
<option [selected]="!form.get('processType').value" [value]="null" disabled>
    {{'type' | translate}}
</option>
```